# Alert app script not work after add in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I create code for alert:

```
function alert() {
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     var value = sheet.getRange("F6").getValue();
     var alter = sheet.getRange("E6").getValue();

    Logger.log(value)
    if (value == alter)
       Logger.log('yes')
       SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("the pice is avilable")
    }
```

it's work fine but after add `=alert()` in cell not working give me #ERROR `Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. (line 9).`

Comment: Try to change the name of the function. `ALERT()` for example.

Answer (score 2):

Ui Dialogs typically have to be triggered by a user action. (e.g. click on a menu item or a button that triggers the function)

> Typically, these elements are opened from menu items.

You could just create a menu item or button and assign the function but you will need to click on it to be triggered.

But based on your current usage, it seems you want to use `alert` automatically every time E6 and F6 are equal. Then most likely you'd like the workaround I did which you can use. See the code below that utilizes `onEdit()`

#### Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  // if edited cell is E6 or F6 and sheet name is "Sheet1"
  if (row == 6 && (col == 5 || col == 6) && sheet.getName() == "Sheet1") {
    var value = sheet.getRange("F6").getValue();
    var alter = sheet.getRange("E6").getValue();

    if (value == alter){
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("the price is available")
    }
  }
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Only editing E6 and F6 of "Sheet1" will trigger the `alert`.

#### Reference:

- [Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Workspace Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)